# JavaScript - splitting window.location.href returns undefined

Tags: javascript, split, undefined

I have the following code JavaScript:

```
var url = window.location.href;

var link = url.split('?link=');

link[1] = "http://goo.gl/" + link[1];
link[2] = "http://goo.gl/" + link[2];

function ad(){
  window.location.href = link[1];
}

function ac(){
  window.open(link[2], '_blank');
}
```

And there is a link:

```
<a href="javascript:ac();" onclick="ad();">ACCESS</a>
```

The problem is that in some computers, the split is not working.

For exemple: If the link is `mySite.com/link.html?link=wfijOp?link=atGdj`.
It should give me `goo.gl/wfijOp` and `goo.gl/atGdj` instead of `goo.gl/undefined` and `goo.gl/undefined`.

What is the problem with those computers?

Comment: It is probably because you are trying to access arrays element that does not exist. Arrays are zero based, so if you want to capture second element in an array you should write link[1].

Comment: @black123 I think he has the desired behavior. `link[0]` would give the `http://..../link.html` part, no?

Comment: as a general note though, query string parameters should be separated with `&param=value` not `?`. `?` is only used to separate query string from the path

Comment: What kind kind of computers are having issues? Are you noticing that it's a problem in particular browsers or OS'es?

Comment: @arcyqwerty they are using windows 8.1, google chrome v. 37. I have no idea why they are having this issue. Everyone else are okay!

Comment: @black123 link[0] give me the mySite.com/link.html part.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos Dos Santos. What gives you `link[1]` and `link[2]`?

Comment: Can you try a `console.log(url)` and `console.log(link)` and tell us what you get? It's _extremely_ unlikely that the `.split()` function itself is failing; it seems more likely that `window.location.href` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Can you see what the value of `window.location.href` is before the split? Maybe the second '?' is being url encoded by the browser or is being stripped off?

Comment: The wierdest thing here is that the code does not work for few computer's people. It is bizar because the link goes to the page goog.gl/undefined. The code actually works partially.

Comment: Wait you've use `javascript:` in an href and then an inline `onclick=` attribute, my inside coder just died a little. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/227176

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce using Chrome 37 (I don't have win 8.1 but it should be running same JS interpreter). Perhaps the URL got messed up for those users? (or they manually modified it?) Do you know the exact url's that they are having issues with?

Comment: I found the problem. Some of the browsers were converting the ?link= into %3Flink%3D. Then, the split was not getting to find the ?link=. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Usually `?` is used for separating the query string from the path (see comment above). Try using another separator like `link=abcd,efgh,ijkl`.  You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1059070) to get the query string variable.

Comment: I got it! I am using ...link.html?separador1233545separadorFHEIBVE. And I get split by "separador". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @arcyqwerty! I did what you suggested.

> Usually ? is used for separating the query string from the path (see
>   comment above). Try using another separator like link=abcd,efgh,ijkl.
>   You can use this to get the query string variable. – @arcyqwerty

[Go to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084516/javascript-splitting-window-location-href-returns-undefined#comment42679134_27084516)